# Consolidate several trivial JSF Views

Tags: jsf, facelets

I'm new to JSF, so please forgive me if I'm asking a stupid question.

Suppose I have a `common.xhtml` file that can be reused by several screens. In fact, the only difference between the screens is the backing bean. For example:

**URL: `~/person`**

```
<ui:composition template="common.xhtml">
  <ui:param name="bean" value="#{personBean}" />
</ui:composition>
```

**URL: `~/vehicle`**

```
<ui:composition template="common.xhtml">
  <ui:param name="bean" value="#{vehicleBean}" />
</ui:composition>
```

**URL: `~/location`**

```
<ui:composition template="common.xhtml">
  <ui:param name="bean" value="#{locationBean}" />
</ui:composition>
```

**URL: `~/food`**

```
<ui:composition template="common.xhtml">
  <ui:param name="bean" value="#{foodBean}" />
</ui:composition>
```

etc...

Is there a way I can avoid creating all of these trivial xhtml files? Can I somehow dynamically set the backing bean and just point each of these URLs directly to the `common.xhtml` file?

Comment: You could try using CDI and a producer for the `bean` which produces one of the actual beans you need.

Comment: But are you actually sure it really is common? Looking at the bean names I suspect a design flaw.